# Upgrade python package from 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 to 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 on ubuntu12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I wanna upgrade python package from 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 to 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2
When I execute command "sudo apt-get install python", ubuntu always told me [python is the latest version]

Is there any way to upgrade my python package on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to manully download the python 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 package and install it. Currently, It works well